# Output array contains "nan" values

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I've a function to compute FFT as pthread thread. Since I've two different inputs, I've two threads with same FFT function. I am using mutex to let threads access shared variables without a problem. The code works well however my output array contains some "nan" values alongside with proper values. When I use function like below without mutex, everything works great.

```
int main(){
    while (1) {
        pthread_create(&thread[1],NULL,compute_FFT,&arguments[1]);

        pthread_join(thread[1],Output[1]);

        pthread_create(&thread[2],NULL,compute_FFT,&arguments[2]);

        pthread_join(thread[2],Output[2]);
    } 
}
```

But when I include while (1) in thread function itself and use mutex, Output array has "nan" values.

```
void *compute_FFT(void* arg){
    struct arg_struct *data = (struct arg_struct *)arg;

    while (1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&fft_mutex);

        data->base = data->fft->in;

        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            data->base[i].re =  Queue[data->number][i]; data->base[i].im =0.0;
        }

        usleep(1);

        gpu_fft_execute(data->fft);
        data->base = data->fft->out;

        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            FFT_out[data->number][i] = sqrt(((data->base[i].re)*(data->base[i].re))+((data->base[i].im)*(data->base[i].im))); 
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&fft_mutex);
    }
}
```

As you can see in first image, output array contains no "nan" values and in the second one it has "nan" values as well as proper values. Those are just part of output array. It normally has 1024 items.

[image: This is the output when I use pthread_create and join together like in code above] [image: Output with "nan" values]

Comment: It would be good if you included some example input data, the expected output for that data and the actual output for that data

Comment: I suggest troubleshooting with a single thread first.  In fact, I suggest just making it single-threaded altogether, for with substantially the whole thread function protected by a mutex, you're not going to get any concurrency anyway.

Comment: It never makes any sense to create a new thread, and then join the thread on the very next line.  The whole point of using threads is for them to execute code _concurrently_.  There is no concurrency if thread A starts a new thread B, and then thread A does nothing else except wait for thread B to die.

Comment: If you remove the `join` calls, you'll have two concurrent calls to `compute_FFT()`, but you'll still have no _parallel computation_.  The reason is, `compute_FFT()` only does work while keeping `fft_mutex` locked.  Since only one thread can have a mutex locked at any given time, only one activation of `compute_FFT()` will be able to do any work at any given time.